# Creating help files in Qt

Tags: qt, helper

I have been looking at `QHelpEngine` and `QHelpEngineCore`, and I was wondering if there is a nice guide on how to start making a help file.

Answer (score 2):

QAssistant was theviewer for html help files.

The new [QHelp](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qthelp-framework.html) framework uses a single compiled help file and includes a set of classes to implement a viewer in your app and some standalone tools to build the help file

Answer (score 1):

Ironically I find it difficult to locate this information in the Qt manual. It's [under QAssistant](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/assistant-custom-help-viewer.html).

Comment: Same. I heard that QAssistant is outdated :/

Comment: @Kazuma: I wasn't implying you had to use QAssistant. The information you were asking for is accessible through that part of the manual. Whether you choose to display it yourself in a custom viewer or in QAssistant is irrelevant. It's the same process i.e. you create .qhp and .qhcp files and produce .qch and .qhc files from them.